# Sending a Word document over HTTP Post in Business Central without OnPrem scope

Tags: ms-word, azure-functions, httprequest, dynamics-business-central

I need to be able to send a Word document over HTTP POST in Business Central. It needs to be sent to an Azure Function that takes in two Word documents.
How would I go about uploading the Word documents to Business Central (I Assume through UploadIntoStream) and then sending the files over HTTP?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct, you need to upload the file into a stream and send it over HTTP. Depending on your azure function you need to either base64 encode it or send it as a binary. This should help you on your way.

The below is mockup code that tells you how to insert an uploaded file into a HTTP request but it does not contain a fully working, authenticated HTTP request. That depends on you Azure Function setup.

```
    procedure SendUploadedFileToAPI() result: JsonObject
    var
        Base64Convert: Codeunit "Base64 Convert";
        Instr: InStream;
        jObject: JsonObject;
        Client: HttpClient;
        Response: HttpResponseMessage;
        Content: HttpContent;
        ContentHeaders: HttpHeaders;
        UploadFilename: Text;
        SelectFileLbl: Label 'Select a file';
        CannotConnectErr: Label 'Cannot connect';
    begin
        UploadIntoStream(SelectFileLbl, '', 'All files (*.*)|*.*', UploadFilename, InStr);

        // Use a json with base64
        jObject.Add('file', Base64Convert.ToBase64(Instr));
        Content.WriteFrom(Format(jObject));
        Content.GetHeaders(ContentHeaders);
        ContentHeaders.Clear();
        ContentHeaders.Add('Content-Type', 'application/json');

        // Or send as binary
        Content.WriteFrom(Instr);
        ContentHeaders.Add('Content-Type', 'application/json');

        if not Client.Post('url', Content, Response) then
            Error(CannotConnectErr);
    end;
```